# Phase margin concept: why can there be instability when the gain never reaches 0dB?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

If the open-loop transfer function is always below 0dB but the phase crosses or approaches 180 degrees, the closed-loop system can still be unstable. Why? Example: open-loop transfer function $\frac{0.5}{s-5}$

I see this related question but the example is stable so it doesn't answer my question: [Gain and Phase Margins from Bode Plot](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36570/gain-and-phase-margins-from-bode-plot)

Comment: What text book are you following ? The concept of phase/gain margin are allowed to be used with open loop **stable** systems. For use with open loop open loop **unstable systems** (like the you posted above) you have to use the full [Nyquist Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion)

Comment: The above answer is correct. With unity feedback the closed loop has a pole at plus 4.5 which is unstable.

Comment: What makes you say that it is always below 0dB? Is it just because it has 0.5 in the numerator? Because (1) that can always be re-written (2) you can't ignore the denominator.